# python Reading file containing \x0a as \n not as \\x0a in python

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I have xml file which contains hex characters \x0a. I want to convert them into proper unicode characters like \n in python.

Whenever i try to read the files it escapes the backslash characters.

For example i my file contents are

```
get EtqLt5fwmRBE\x0a
```

Then after reading the files the representation of string comes out to be

```
get EtqLt5fwmRBE\\x0a
```

But what i want is to convert `\x0a` to `\n`

There are not `\x0a` in files. There are other characters as well. For examples one of the `repr()` of line in file is

```
\\x7c12\\x7c5\\x7c\\x0a
```

Expected output for above is

```
|12|5|
```

Comment: Are you outputting `repr()` results? That's also the case when printing containers. `\\x0a` is a literal ``\``, `x`, `0`, `a` sequence of four characters. Just replace that sequence with `\n`?

Comment: no if i output without repr then in the contents are `get EtqLt5fwmRBE\x0a`.

Comment: Is there a way to convert it to get EtqLt5fwmRBE\n ?

Comment: Yes, that confirms what I am asking; you have a sequence of 4 characters. `str.replace()` those: `yourstr.replace(r'\x0a', '\n')`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I want a generalise way there are not only \x0a other special characters are also present

Comment: Then specify that in your question. It'd be helpful if you actually included the `repr()` output of some samples with the expected output.

Comment: I do wonder how this data was produced? Did you put Python string data into the XML file with `repr()` perhaps?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I had a xml file containing this data. I am trying to parse this xml file to get the proper formatted string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run your text through the `string_escape` (Python 2 only, produces a bytestring) or `unicode_escape` (Python 2 and 3, produces a unicode string) codecs.

How you apply these depends on your Python version (2 or 3) and if the input is a byte string (`str` in Python 2, `bytes` in Python 3) or Unicode string (`unicode` in Python 2, `str` in Python 3).

Python 2, if you have either a byte string *or* unicode string, just call `decode()`:

```
fixed = yourstring.decode('unicode_escape')
```

In Python 3, use `bytestring.decode(...)` if you have bytes. If you have `str`, encode to Latin-1 first (as `unicode_escape` will use that to decode any non-ASCII codepoints!):

```
fixed = yourstring.encode('latin1').decode('unicode_escape')
```

Demo in Python 2:

```
>>> '\\x7c12\\x7c5\\x7c\\x0a'.decode('unicode_escape')
u'|12|5|\n'
>>> u'\\x7c12\\x7c5\\x7c\\x0a'.decode('unicode_escape')
u'|12|5|\n'
```

In Python 3:

```
>>> b'\\x7c12\\x7c5\\x7c\\x0a'.decode('unicode_escape')
'|12|5|\n'
>>> '\\x7c12\\x7c5\\x7c\\x0a'.encode('latin1').decode('unicode_escape')
'|12|5|\n'
```